# specifying variable field width in sscanf

Tags: c, string, printf, scanf

I have the following `sscanf` statement:

```
sscanf(line, "%*s %511s %511s",protocol,hexdata)
```

Now line consists of the following form `" a b c "`. It's clear I am ignoring the value `a` by giving `%*s`. I take the values of `b` and `c` into protocol and data.

What I would like to do is I dont want to hardcode 511. I am just unable to do so. I tried the following but it does not seem to work.

```
    sprintf(log_buffer,"1234 56789");
    printf("\n Buffer is : %s \n",log_buffer);

    strcpy(format,"%*s ");                    // gives %*s
    sprintf(format1, "%%%ds", 5);            // gives %5s
    printf("\n Format is : %s ",format);
    printf("\n Format1 is : %s ",format1);
    strcat(format,format1);
    printf("\n new format is : %s ",format);

    sscanf(log_buffer,format,name);

    printf(" Name is : %s ",name);
    printf(" \n Size of name %d ",strlen(name));
```

This gives me junk value.

Sample output:

```
Buffer is : 1234 56789
Format is : %*s
Format1 is : %5s
new format is : %*s %5s
Name is : �
8r�2�%*s %5s  
Size of name 15
```

What is wrong here ? I just have to prevent hardcoding variable field.

Comment: what does the declarations of your char arrays look like?

Comment: my declarations are as follows                                    char log_buffer[20]={0},format[5]={0},name[8]={0},format1[5]={0}

Comment: It works for me: http://ideone.com/wkWzN

Comment: oh what a blunder :( thanks a ton ! really silly of me .

Answer (score 2):

> my declarations are as follows char format[5]={0};

The `format` string can hold 4 chracters and the zero terminator. That is not enough for `"%*s %5s"`!

Increase the array size.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are overwriting memory in one of your char arrays. You have not shown the sizes of your `format,format1, name` and `log_buffer` so I am just guessing since other than that the code looks ok.

When running where each array is dimensioned to 32 bytes it gives the following output (VS2008):

```
 Buffer is : 1234 56789

 Format is : %*s
 Format1 is : %5s
 new format is : %*s %5s  Name is : 56789
 Size of name 5
```

Comment: yes i made a horrible mistake allocating buffer for format :( i got it now . thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should note that the 511 value provided in the format string does not means that the actual string read has that number of characters.

The 511 value is provided to instruct `sscanf` about how many characters it can write into your destination variable (`name` in your example). You have to regard it as a security to prevent buffer overrun.

Comment: yes i know the importance of 511 . But think what would happen if tommorow someone changed my buffer length from 512 i.e line[512] to line[1024] . Then the 511 would also need to be changed else there will be errors and if a new person sees the code it will be difficult to catch . So what i want to do it line[LENGTH] and use the same #define LENGTH to construct the sscanf (without hardcoding ) . guess better coding standards